# QWebEngine and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt5, qtwebengine, qt5.5

I upgraded my project to Qt 5.5.1. Because of the deprecated QWebKit, I want to switch to QWebEngine with the whole project. The project needs to be compiled for Windows and Linux. I just found out, that MinGW does not support QWebEngine, so I wanted to use nmake. But what is with Linux OS now?

How can I deploy QWebEngine (or QML WebEngine) for Linux instead of MinGW?

Is there maybe a solution, which would work for both OS in the same way?

Comment: What is the actual question? QWebEngine works on Linux.

Comment: How? We compile our projects with mingw for linux, and mingw does not have QWebEngine.

Comment: Well, you just don't do it. Install a Windows VM and compile with Visual Studio. What's the point of a Linux->Windows cross-compilation using MinGW in 2015?

Comment: The point is, mingw does not deliver a QtWebEngineProcess application and no Qt5WebEngineWidgets.dll/suo as I know. Or am I wrong?